# Update table details using XML Through Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

First off all I had go through with the related questions about this topic but none of them solve my problem because my xml has some different structure. That's why I have ask a question here about this problem.

```
<Root>
    <MyData>
    <Data>
    <EID>1</EID>
    <PID>246</PID>
    <SID>1</SID>
    </Data>

    <UpdateData>
    <TemplateID>42</TemplateID>
    <UserID>12</UserID>
    </UpdateData>

    <UpdateData>
    <TemplateID>55</TemplateID>
    <UserID>2</UserID>
    </UpdateData>

    <UpdateData>
    <TemplateID>61</TemplateID>
    <UserID>2</UserID>
    </UpdateData>

    <UpdateData>
    <TemplateID>66</TemplateID>
    <UserID>2</UserID>
    </UpdateData>

    <UpdateData>
    <TemplateID>76</TemplateID>
    <UserID>2</UserID>
    </UpdateData>

    <UpdateData>
    <TemplateID>79</TemplateID>
    <UserID>2</UserID>
    </UpdateData>

    </MyData>
    </Root>
```

I have an xml like above and I want to update each `UserId` from that XML in my database table using certain conditions.

I have included my table structure below

Table Name : `UpdateDetails`

Columns : `EID, PID, SID, TemplateID, UserID`  All columns are `int` datatype

Normal query will be something like below

```
update UpdateDetails  
set UserID = @UserID 
where EID = @EID 
  and PID = @PID 
  and SID = @SID 
  and TemplateID = @TemplateID;
```

but i don't know how can i take thease all values from xml and make an update.

i had tried something like below but it will not work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Details
@xml text 
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @intPointer int;
declare @PId int;
declare @EId int;
declare @SId int;



set @PId =(SELECT data.item.value('PID', 'int') AS PId
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Root/MyData/Data') data(item));

set @EId =(SELECT data.item.value('EID', 'int') AS EId
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Root/MyData/Data') Delegatedata(item));

set @SId =(SELECT data.item.value('SID', 'int') AS SId
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Root/MyData/Data') data(item));


exec sp_xml_preparedocument @intPointer output, @xml 


      update UpdateDetails set UserID=

 (Select      * 
      from OpenXml(@intPointer,'/Root/MyData/Data',3)
    With (UserID int 'UserID'))

where PID=@PID and SID=@SID and EID=@EID and TemplateID=(Select      * 
      from OpenXml(@intPointer,'/Root/MyData/Data',3)
    With (TemplateID int 'TemplateID'))


END
```

Please help me to solve this isuue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: firstly 2 of your xml closing nodes: `</MyData> + </Root>` don't have opening nodes, secondly your stored proc params, e.g. `@PeriodId ` aren't being used as you: `set @PId`, please correct these issues in the post.

Comment: @Tanner it was a mistake i had corrected now can you please look on it now ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: your XML still has flaws - `<SID>` is closed with `</ID>` which doesn't work, `<ChecklistData>` is closed with `</UpdateData>` . Please try to pay more attention to providing a **functioning** data sample!

Comment: You can pass data using [table valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx) and avoid parsing entirely. A simple `INSERT ... FROM @t` would be enough. A BULK INSERT operation would be even faster. Better parse the XML data on the client (or simply don't convert to XML) and use TVPs or BULK INSERT to pass the data

Comment: If for some reason you *have* to use XML, use the [xml data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339(v=sql.100).aspx) to avoid errors and parsing by hand

Comment: @marc_s i had corrected those thanks for your attension

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the data amound is very high so i need to pass the entire data once other wise i need to call the sp for lot of time it cause delay, i am also looking for bulkupdate but i don't know how can i do it here can you please provide an example

Comment: If there is a lot of data *don't* use XML or try to pass it in one go. That's what BULK INSERT is for. You can use the SqlBulkInsert class from .NET code if you want to pass a lot of data data from the client, although nothing beats the performance of loading data from a local file. Batching rows also helps immensely because the server doesn't have to keep locks and transaction log entries active waiting for the entire dataset to be stored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using standard native XQuery, you can fairly easily parse that XML:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '.... your XML .....' 

SELECT
    EID = XC.value('(EID)[1]', 'int'),
    PID = XC.value('(PID)[1]', 'int'),
    SID = XC.value('(SID)[1]', 'int'),
    TemplateID = XUC.value('(TemplateID)[1]', 'int'),
    UserID = XUC.value('(UserID)[1]', 'int')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/Root/MyData/Data') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    @input.nodes('/Root/MyData/UpdateData') AS XUT(XUC)
```

This gives you an output of:

```
EID PID SID TemplateID  UserID
------------------------------
 1  246  1     42         12
 1  246  1     55          2
 1  246  1     61          2
 1  246  1     66          2
 1  246  1     79          2
```

Based on that, you should be able to formulate an `UPDATE` statement that does what you need it to do.

**Please**: don't use `TEXT` datatype anymore! It's deprecated - and since this is really XML - use the `XML` datatype!

So try stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Details
     @input XML
AS
BEGIN
    WITH XmlCte AS 
    (
        SELECT
            EID = XC.value('(EID)[1]', 'int'),
            PID = XC.value('(PID)[1]', 'int'),
            SID = XC.value('(SID)[1]', 'int'),
            TemplateID = XUC.value('(TemplateID)[1]', 'int'),
            UserID = XUC.value('(UserID)[1]', 'int')
        FROM 
            @input.nodes('/Root/MyData/Data') AS XT(XC)
        CROSS APPLY
            @input.nodes('/Root/MyData/UpdateData') AS XUT(XUC)
    )
    UPDATE ud
    SET UserID = x.UserID
    FROM dbo.UpdateDetails ud
    INNER JOIN XmlCte x ON ud.EID = x.EID 
                        AND ud.PID = x.PID 
                        AND ud.SID = x.SID 
                        AND ud.TemplateID = x.TemplateID
END
```

The `XmlCte` CTE (Common Table Expression) basically parses the `@Input` XML into a relational table, and then applies the `UPDATE` statement using those rows as the values to update your table with.

Comment: thanks for your answer sir i will look on it .+1 for your valid suggesctions

Comment: A TVP would be a better choice for what is essentially flat data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you please  provide an example

Comment: I already posted the link as a comment to the question: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx . The article even compares TVPs with BULK INSERT

Comment: when i try with your method i got something like EID 1
PID 246
SID 1
TemplateID NULL
UserID NULL

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: that would be the case if your XML really doesn't look like that one you posted here ......

Comment: @marc_s i have one more doubt how can i use these values in my update query ? can you please provide a example ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: I posted the whole stored procedure to use ..... including the `UPDATE` statement .....

Comment: @ow thanks for your help, i had already done that .anyway thanks a lot.i think i can replace my update method with yours it  looks great

Answer (score 0):

Pass list of to this method to get datatable

```
private DataTable GetSupplementaryLessonDataTable(List<SupplementaryLesson> supplementaryLessons)
{
        DataTable dtsupplementaryLessons = new DataTable("supplementaryLessons");
        dtsupplementaryLessons.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LessonId",
                     Type.GetType("System.Int32")));

        dtsupplementaryLessons.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsSmartSyllabus",
                     Type.GetType("System.Int32")));

        foreach (var item in supplementaryLessons)
        {
            DataRow drRow = dtsupplementaryLessons.NewRow();  
            drRow["LessonId"] = item.Id;
            drRow["IsSmartSyllabus"] = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
            dtsupplementaryLessons.Rows.Add(drRow);
        }

        return dtsupplementaryLessons;
}
```

Then convert to xml and pass that as a SQL parameter

```
using (StringWriter swStringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    supplementaryLessonsDataTable.WriteXml(swStringWriter);
    string strsupplementaryLessonsDataTable = swStringWriter.ToString();

    Parameter[] lstParams = new Parameter[]
                 {
                     new Parameter("@supplementaryLessons",strsupplementaryLessonsDataTable,ParameterDirection.Input,DbType.Xml)
                 };

    int intRetValue = DataBaseHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("Admin_UpdateBulkSupplementaryLesson", lstParams);
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Admin_UpdateBulkSupplementaryLesson
    @EmpDetails xml
AS
BEGIN
    WITH XmlCte AS 
    (
        SELECT
            CAST(colx.query('data(LessonId)') AS varchar) AS LessonId,
            CAST(colx.query('data(IsSmartSyllabus)') AS varchar) AS IsSmartSyllabus
        FROM
            @EmpDetails.nodes('DocumentElement/supplementaryLessons') AS TABX(COLX)
    )    
    UPDATE L
    SET L.IsSmartSyllabus = x.IsSmartSyllabus
    FROM Lesson L
    INNER JOIN XmlCte x ON L.LessonId = x.LessonId 
END
```